# How do I know if my algorithm is fast? (Gauss's Circle Problem)

Tags: python, algorithm, number-theory

When I wrote [my thesis](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?dswid=-766&pid=diva2%3A1705254&c=5&searchType=SIMPLE&language=en&query=Kenny+Jonsson&af=%5B%5D&aq=%5B%5B%5D%5D&aq2=%5B%5B%5D%5D&aqe=%5B%5D&noOfRows=50&sortOrder=author_sort_asc&sortOrder2=title_sort_asc&onlyFullText=false&sf=all) on number theory, I included my take on an algorithm for finding the number of integer lattice points in a circle. I did not go into too much detail about it, since I couldn't find out if it was fast or not, compared to existing algorithms.

I read a lot of pages concerning Gauss's Circle Problem but I could not find many code examples. The fastest one I found was the following, from [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html):

```
def wolfram_circle_points(r):
   iterpoints = 0

   for i in range(1, int(r // 1) + 1):
      iterpoints += int((r**2-i**2)**(1/2) // 1)
   return 1 + 4*int(r // 1) + 4*iterpoints
```

My algorithm takes about 60% less time to run than the one from Wolfram:

```
def my_circle_points(r):
   if r == 0:
      return 1

   a = int(-1 * (r/2**(1/2)) // 1 * -1)
   iterpoint = 0
   for x in range(a, int(r // 1) + 1):
      calcs = x - (r**2-x**2)**(1/2)
      if calcs - int(calcs // 1) == 0:
         iterpoint += int(calcs // 1) - 1
      else:
         iterpoint += int(calcs // 1)
   return 4*a + 4*int(r // 1)**2 - 8*iterpoint - 3
```

How do I know if this is worth anything to anybody (time savings-wise)? Is there a database that holds the current fastest algorithms for a bunch of different tasks?

Comment: I am pretty sure the code can be speed up by a factor of 10 by implementing it in a system programming language (C, C++, Rust, ...) instead of python.

Comment: 60% is not a significant saving. As said by Unlikus, just changing the language could make a much bigger difference. What matters most is the asymptotic behavior, i.e. the cost as a function of n.

Comment: There isn't and there will never be a repository of the "fastest" algorithms, because program speed depends on a too large number of factors among which computer architecture and input dataset.

Comment: I should have been clearer. I did not mean that my code is faster (I am not a programmer, so bad implementations is to be expected). The algorithm from Wolfram will loop n times, while mine while loop less than n/3 times. So both are O(n), I guess.

Comment: The wolfram algorithm was written for clarity.  In practice, starting the iteration at .7r is a good and simple idea, although it would be pretty obvious to anyone trying to write a fast version of this algorithm.  I think an expert who put a *lot* of effort into writing a fast version of this algorithm would end up with something quite clever that reduced asymptotic complexity.  Regarding "how do I know..." , well, same as in your field, really -- experience.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Ah, figures. If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.